# Removing only empty parenthesis in R

Tags: r, regex

I am working with some headers and I  need to remove parenthesis in the headers but only where is nothing inside but to keep the others if it has the unit of measure. e.g.

```
"Sample_No ()"  - Sample_No
"SOC (%)" - "SOC (%)"
```

## Example

[image: Pasted example]

Comment: I've edited this but for operations involving only textual input and output it may be better to provide simple text. It will the question more accessible, especially for people using screen readers, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is empty parentheses match the open parentheses followed by the closing parentheses without any other characters and replace with blank (`""`) in `gsub` (if there is a chance of more than one matches) or with the example even `sub` is enough)

```
gsub("\\s*\\(\\)", "", v1)
```

-output

```
[1] "Sample_No" "SOC (%)"
```

---

Or use `str_remove` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
trimws(str_remove_all(v1, fixed("()")))
[1] "Sample_No" "SOC (%)"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("Sample_No ()", "SOC (%)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `gsub` with a regular expression. `\\s` denotes whitespace `\\(` and `\\)` the parentheses that have to be escaped.

```
x <- c("Sample_No ()", "Sample_No", "SOC (%)", "SOC (%)")

gsub('\\s\\(\\)', '', x)
# [1] "Sample_No" "Sample_No" "SOC (%)"   "SOC (%)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `gsub` you could do:

```r
header <- c("Sample_No ()", "SOC (%)")

gsub("\\s*\\(\\)", "", header)
#> [1] "Sample_No" "SOC (%)"
```

Comment: @TomasV You are welcome. But in my opinion akrun deserves the credit for the accepted answer. Not only was he the first to answer but also is his answer more complete than mine.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, you may wan to explore the [`stringi`](https://stringi.gagolewski.com) package. The code below also trims potential empty spaces that may be left after the operation.

```
vecA <- c("Sample_No ()", "SOC (%)")
stringi::stri_trim_both(
    stringi::stri_replace_all(str = vecA, replacement = "",  fixed = "()")
)
# [1] "Sample_No" "SOC (%)"
```

This particular operation is trivial, but [`stringi`](https://stringi.gagolewski.com) comes in handy for more complex operations.